# No JDK named ‘null’ found

Tags: jenkins

When running a Jenkin's job, I get the error:

```
No JDK named ‘null’ found
```

What does that mean?

I just updated jenkins using yum update, and I'm running on centos 7.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which Jenkins version you're using, there is a bug in Jenkins (currently tracked by the community) - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31217

For a workaround to resolve your issue, try the following:
Go to 'Manage Jenkins' -> 'Configure System', add 2 dummy JDKs (No path required). From the build job config, select the jdk you want to use from the dropdown in the top half of the configuration.